# Project assemblies could not be loaded

Tags: sharepoint, gac

I have a solution in which it has two projects, one a SharePoint Project and another a webforms (asp.net) project. Whenever, I deploy the sharepoint project to the SharePoint 2013 server, it works fine. However, when I run the webform project, this error appears.

> The Entity Framework provider type
>   'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices,
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file
>   for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'
>   could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is
>   used and that the assembly is available to the running application.
>   See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more
>   information.

The entity framework is installed correctly on the server as I am using entity framework in the sharepoint project as well. This error is related to the assemblies of the applications. Perhaps, could it be due to the GAC?
When I run the project on a normal server, then it is fine.

Comment: I do not understand what has to do with the sharepoint project. Anyway check the asp.net web.config for the connectionString used into the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a SharePoint Project as well as a ASP.NET project that share a common Class library. This error was generated because I was trying to deploy ASP.NET project via Visual Studio while having the SharePoint Project installed as a Farm Solution. Apparently, this conflicted. 
I retracted the SharePoint Solution and it worked.